# Concatenate Bold Text with Binding Text in Maui Label

Tags: format, label, maui, bold

I'm trying to concatenate text in a Maui Label and I want part of the text to be bold. The examples I've found seem mostly for wpf and not Maui.
This gives me the concatenated text:

```
    <Label
        x:Name="SecondTip"
        FontSize="16" 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        Text="{Binding FirstActionRowText, StringFormat='Recommendation: {0}'}"
    />
```

But how can I set 'Recommendation:' to Bold? I've been trying things like setting TextType to Html and adding Bold tags without success.
Also interested in how I'd format the binding text too?

EDIT: I've achieved the bold formatting like this:

```
        <Label x:Name="SecondTip">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="Recommendation: " FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
                    <Span Text="{Binding FirstActionRowText}" FontSize="16" />
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
```

However, the result gives me slightly smaller text than when creating a normal label and setting Text, so it looks slight odd. How can I match the style of the default Label?

Comment: Use [FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label?view=net-maui-7.0#use-formatted-text)

Comment: @Jason thanks - almost there, but the text size is slightly different with the 2 approaches above. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you may try set the character spacing bigger or smaller, just like:

```
<Span Text="Recommendation: " FontAttributes="Bold"
 CharacterSpacing="-0.5"     FontSize="16"  />
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This gets me pretty close but the text still isnt quite the same. Would be good to know the defaults using each method

Comment: That seems a known issue on Github. [Bold Changes Font Size on Labels](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2168)